# Firefox on MacOS: Default filename when downloading

Tags: macos, finder, automation, firefox

When downloading from Firefox on MacOS, I would like the filename to be prefixed by the ISO-date (`YYYY-MM-DD-original-filename.extension`). This can be achieved with a folder action in the downloads folder, but I want it to be in all folders, so a folder action is not an ideal solution.

If possible I'd like all new files to have the prefix, regardless of the creating app.

Is this possible?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best with your question!

Comment: You could write an apple script to rename all your files to this format.

Comment: @historystamp; thank you, but that is the same as creating a folder action. I would like to be given the option when saving a file. It might not need the same date as the creation date.

Comment: fyi: I don't see the utility of making all new files begin with the date.  You loose the ability to sort the files by name. What the diff between sorting by date and adding the date in front of the file?  I can see utility of putting the date in front of downloaded files.

Comment: I looked around and didn't see an extension to do this with the latest versions of Firefox. You could try to convince an author of a Download manager to add support. https://flashgot.net/screenshots/

Comment: https://www.downthemall.net/ has a rename capability but doesn't run on the latest version of firefox. dtm is reported to run in Waterfox

Comment: @historystamp, the given date does not always equal the creation date, the modified date or the last opened date. The ISO-date exists to be able to sort and group documents on year, month and date. I have solved my quandary by creating a service that supplies the current date and mapped it to a keyboard shortcut. I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution was to make an *Automator workflow* to run a shell script, and map it to a universal keyboard shortcut. This has been very useful to me, so here it is:

```
# echo `date +"%Y-%m-%d "` + " "
A=`date +%F`
echo "$A "
```

[image: Screenshot of opening Automator and create new workflow]

Open Automator and create new *workflow*.

[image: Screenshot of creating workflow to run shell script]

Set workflow to receive text from any application, choose to replace the selected text and add *Run Shell Script*. Choose `/bin/bash` and `pass input to stdin`. Paste the script and save.

[image: Screenshot of *Keyboard Shortcuts* in *System Preferences*]
Go to *System Preferences*, choose *Keyboard* and *Shortcuts*. Choose *Services*, find yours on the list and map a shortcut.